# Outlook 2010 Removing Custom Ribbon Groups

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, ribbon

My outlook keeps deleting all custom groups that I created for my ribbon. The groups last about 24 hours, not even. Sometimes it happens twice a day, but it randomly removes a custom group.

Does anyone know why this could be happening or a way to fix/workaround it?

I create the custom groups through options > Customize Ribbon

Comment: Through the Options>customize ribbon

Answer (score 0):

When you customise the ribbon, do you create a new command group, or modify an existing one (such as Home (Mail))?

It may be that you need to create a custom group - I have done this before and never have any problems with them removing themselves after a set period of time.

There is a "New Group" button on the bottom of the "Customise" list on the right of the screen.
Click that, give it a name and add your commands & this should solve the problem.

HTH